# Spotify API: search route with genre filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, libspotify

It been few days that I'm trying to make my request work but with no success.
In react, I would like to do a search request with a genre filter as param, I can normally do it as mentioned in the docmentation[text](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search)

When typing the name of any band in the search field, if it is in the genre that I have pre-selected (e.g. rock) it will appear, otherwise nothing happens.

with this code, all tunes, even those of the wrong genre, appear.

Thanks in advance for your help

here is me code snippet:

```
const search = async (accessToken: string | null, searchValue: string, musicalGenre?: string[]) => { 
  const listOfMusicalGenre = musicalGenre?.join('%3A');
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
    q: `${encodeURIComponent(searchValue)}%20genre%3A${listOfMusicalGenre}`,
    type: 'track,artist',
    market: 'FR'
  });

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?${queryParams}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching available genres:', error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that the API supports searching by multiple genres? Assuming it does, other parts of the search API appear to use commas to separate multiple values, and you are using `:`.

To narrow down the issue, you should print out your resolved URL, the value of `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?${queryParams}` and add that to the question.